# SwiftUI Conditionally disable modifier

Tags: swiftui

So say I want to conditionally enable or disable a modifier on a view such as matched geometry effect? As silly as this looks, how would I do this?

```
Image("Test")
   .scaleEffect(self.selectedImageScale)
   .offset(self.selectedImageOffset)
   .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
if disabled {
   .matchedGeometryEffect(id: selectedImage.id, in: self.namespace)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it with a simple extension on the `View`:

```
extension View {

    @ViewBuilder
    public func `if`<T: View, U: View>(
        _ condition: Bool,
        then modifierT: (Self) -> T,
        else modifierU: (Self) -> U
    ) -> some View {

        if condition { modifierT(self) }
        else { modifierU(self) }
    }
}
```

Now you can use it like:

```
Image("Test")
   .scaleEffect(self.selectedImageScale)
   .offset(self.selectedImageOffset)
   .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)

   .if(disabled) { view in
       view.matchedGeometryEffect(id: selectedImage.id, in: self.namespace)
   } else { $0 } // returns unmodified view
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't put an `if` around a modifier, but you can use a ternary statement inside the parameters of the modifier:

```
.matchedGeometryEffect(id: disabled ? 0 : selectedImage.id, in: self.namespace)
```

Not sure if 0 works here for a "disabled" id, depends on your ids.

Comment: This wouldnt actually disable the effect, it would just change what the effect is assigned to. See answer above